# Unit tests for interrupt-heavy code on an embedded system

Tags: c, unit-testing, avr, avr-gcc

I am writing C code for an [AVR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmel_AVR) chip. The code is heavy on [interrupt service routines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_handler) (ISRs) which wait on serial ports, [ADCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog-to-digital_converter) and timers. The ISRs write to buffers which the main loop examines when it gets to them.

I design the buffers so that ISRs can update them while the main loop is reading them. I want to verify that this works. I have unit tests to validate basic operation, but I'm not clear on how to test what happens if an interrupt fires while the main loop is reading a buffer.

My unit tests are really basic--some code in a `main()` function. I run the tests on my Linux box.

Comment: [Unit testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) non-deterministic code? Isn't that a contradiction in terms? (Though it is ***very*** important to test. The failure rate can be on the order of 1% if one is lucky and much lower if one is unlucky.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Threads?

Launch a high-priority thread which calls your ISR at some rate similar to the real thing.
Then in your main, do the buffer read over and over again in a loop.  Validate that the buffer read is not corrupted.

(Maybe this is more of an integration test than a pure unit test.)

Comment: I expect it can be a lot of work using threads to simulate interrupt timing. I wonder if this type of testing is common enough that a package exists that implements it.